# Angular, sharing data between controllers and updating it from one controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have read through a lot of posts about it but still cannot figure what's wrong with my code. I have two controllers - one collecting products for orders per person and the other one showing table with ordered products. Obviously I want them to share the data about orders/products. Unfortunately I cannot make an update to orders table after adding new product.

```
export class OrderReviewController {
    ...
    getProducts = () => {
         this.orderDataFactory.setOrders(this.orderService.getOrdersPerAppointment());
        return this.orderDataFactory.getProducts();
    }
}

export class ProductController {
    ...
    refreshOrdersTable = () => {
        this.ordersData.setOrders(this.orderService.getOrdersPerAppointment());
        this.ordersData.setProducts(undefined);
    }
}

export class OrdersData implements interfaces.IOrdersDataFactory {
    orders: interfaces.IOrder[];
    products: interfaces.ISalesOrderDetail[];

     getOrders = () => {
        return this.orders;
      }

    setOrders = (orders: interfaces.IOrder[]) => {
         this.orders = orders;
     }

     getProducts = () => {
        if (!this.products){
        this.products = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.orders.length; i++) {
             this.products = this.products.concat(this.orders[i].products);
         }
        }
     return this.products;
    }

    setProducts = (products:any) => {
         this.products = products;
    }
}

 `<tr ng-repeat="sample in oc.getProducts()">
     <td><a href="" ng-dblclick="oc.openOrderPopup(sample.SalesOrderId.Id)">{{product.salesordername}}</a></td>
                                        <td><a href="" ng-dblclick="oc.openContactPopup(sample.cdss_contactid.Id)">{{product.customerName}}</a></td>
                                        <td>{{product.title}}</td>
                                        <td>{{product.subject}}</td>
                                        <td>{{product.type}}</td>
                                        <td>{{product.sent ? "yes" : "no"}}</td>
                                    </tr>`
```

Unfortunately onload I get:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: angularjs does not use typescript. angular 2 does. But your template looks like angularjs. Which are you using?

Comment: I have used typescript with Angular 1.x before and I don't think typescript is an issue there. I use Angular 1.5.8

Answer (score 0):

The problem reside in the getProducts() method in the OrdersData class. The problem is that you create a new array every time the function is executed. You should not recreate the products array each time, use some update critera instead to define when to create a new array.

If the orders array is the same as last time, return the same object.

```
getProducts = () => {

    if(!this.products || someUpdateCriteria) {
       this.products = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < this.orders.length; i++) {
            this.products = this.products.concat(this.orders[i].products);
        } 
    }

    return this.products;
}
```

See this article for more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: Hi, please see my updated code according to your suggestion. I can see that getProducts is being called after adding new product (although I know setting this.products for undefined is a bit ugly) but this is not being reflected on the orders table. I still don't know what's the issue...

Comment: How are you calling the refreshOrdersTable function? You may need to run a scope.apply() after updating the product information to refresh your repeater

Comment: I have just double checked and it seems that getProducts is not called after adding product... I am super confused, never had problems with sharing data between controllers before.